# Async only accepted Future and void as return type after upgrade to JDK 17 and Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I just updated my project from JDK 11 to JDK 17 and from Spring Boot 2.7.5 to 3.0.0.

When I try to run my async method, it throws an exception as below

```
com.app.svc.exception.ControllerException: Invalid return type for async method (only Future and void supported): class com.app.svc.model.ResponseModel
```

The code look like this:

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
@Override
public ResponseModel startRequest(RequestModel request, Logger logger) throws Exception { ... }
```

It works before I upgrade so I think not returning as `Future` or `void` is somehow acceptable. Is that changed in JDK 17 or Spring Boot 3.0.0? Or there is something else that I do wrong?

Appreciates any help, thank you!

Comment: Can't believe that worked before update - I have seen "similar" errors long before java 11 was released, more obvious explanation there is `@Async` annotation was previously ignored. btw, you need to write in method body smth. like: `return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(...)`

Comment: I see, so it wasn't supposed to work prior the upgrade anyway! Understood, I have updated to the `CompletableFuture` response and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: If my memory serves me right, in old spring versions that was required to explicitly enable "async mode" via `@EnableAsync`, m.b. smth. has been changed in spring6/boot3

Comment: We do have the `@EnableAsync` annotation actually, wonder why previously never had these error.

Comment: It never worked (or intended to work) with anything other then `void` or a `Future`. However nothing was there preventing you from do so (basically returning nothing making it more or less `void`). That has been fixed in Spring 6 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27734) and now anything else as the supported types wil lead to an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error has been added in Spring Framework 6 (with [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27734)).

In short `@Async` never supported anything other then `void` or a `Future` return type. If you returned something else it would, surprisingly, return `null` instead of the actual value (if async works correctly) because it needs to return immediately from the call. This basically mimics `void`.

Although the supported return types were documented from the beginning of `@Async` (See [the javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) from the first edition of `@Async`) it was never really enforced in the aspect that utilized async.

That last point has been addressed in Spring Framework 6 (with [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27734)), to prevent surprises like the one you had and as documented in aforementioned issue.

The source for Spring Framework 3 (found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3.0.x/org.springframework.aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java#L76))

```java
public Object invoke(final MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {

    Future result = this.asyncExecutor.submit(new Callable<Object>() {
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            try {
                Object result = invocation.proceed();
                if (result instanceof Future) {
                    return ((Future) result).get();
                }
            }
            catch (Throwable ex) {
                ReflectionUtils.rethrowException(ex);
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    if (Future.class.isAssignableFrom(invocation.getMethod().getReturnType())) {
        return result;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can see in the original code it only checked the return type to be a `Future`, if so it would be returned, else it would return `null`.

```java
@Nullable
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected Object doSubmit(Callable<Object> task, AsyncTaskExecutor executor, Class<?> returnType) {
    if (CompletableFuture.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType)) {
        return executor.submitCompletable(task);
    }
    else if (org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType)) {
        return ((org.springframework.core.task.AsyncListenableTaskExecutor) executor).submitListenable(task);
    }
    else if (Future.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType)) {
        return executor.submit(task);
    }
    else if (void.class == returnType) {
        executor.submit(task);
        return null;
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Invalid return type for async method (only Future and void supported): " + returnType);
    }
}
```

In the latest Spring Framework 6 code that has been changed and now checks all supported return types explicitly. If none are found an exception is being thrown. (Code is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/6e08c56076280021542ee086a6ddd971a256c5ca/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java#L283)).